# Sails.js 1.0 find does not automatically return an association

Tags: sails.js

I am using sails.js and its `find()` function no longer returns an association.

In the past I used:

```
XYZ.find()
.populate('field')
.exec(function(err, results){})
```

Right now I use:

```
await find()
```

How can I set `populate` in the new version of `find()`?

Comment: populate() should still work in Sails 1.0 - [here are the current ways to use it](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/populate) with the new version of find().

Answer (score 1):

The usage in Sails 1.0 looks like this:

```
var pets = await Pet.find()
.populate('leashes');

console.log(pets);
console.log(pets[0] && pets[0].leashes);
```